# Extjs XTemplate two same level array loop?

Tags: extjs

I want to use XTempate with the follow json data ,loop the one array in another array,

```
var data = {
    name : 'xxx',
    rowTitleArr : ['1','2','3'],
    colTitleArr : ['a','b','c']
}
var tpl = [
    '{name}',
    '<tpl for="{rowTitleArr}">',
        '----{.}<br>',
        '<tpl for="parent.colTitleArr">',
            '---------{.}<br>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'
];
var t = new Ext.Template(tpl);
t.overwrite(xx,data);
```

but the result is :

```
  ----1
  ---------a  
  ---------b
  ---------c
  ----2
  ----3
```

I want the follow result:

```
  ----1
  --------a
  --------b
  --------c
  ----2
  --------a
  --------b
  --------c
  ----3  
  --------a
  --------b
  --------c
```

why ? I make a mistake? 
  thanks ahead!

Comment: Why did you edit that back to just plain text, this is not very readable at all...

Answer (score 2):

I made some small changes to your template:

this is working for me:

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/2WEVE/

```
var tpl = [
    '{name}',
    '<br/>',
    '<tpl for="rowTitleArr">',
    '----{.}<br>',
        '<tpl for="parent.colTitleArr">',
    '---------{.}<br>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'];
```