# ExtJS XTemplate Iterating over two arrays parallely

Tags: arrays, extjs, xtemplate

I am browsing through two arrays inside an XTemplate and I want to display their values side by side.

I found something similar mentioned here:

[Extjs XTemplate two same level array loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069000/extjs-xtemplate-two-same-level-array-loop)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'test',
    height: 300,
    width: 300
});

var data = {
    name: 'xxx',
    rowTitleArr: ['1', '2', '3'],
    colTitleArr: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
var tpl = [
    '<br/>',
    '<tpl for="rowTitleArr">',
    '{.}<br>',
        '<tpl for="parent.colTitleArr">',
    '---{.}<br>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'];

var t = new Ext.XTemplate(tpl);
panel.update(t.apply(data));
});
```

This gives the result:

```
1
---a
---b
---c
2
---a
---b
---c
3
---a
---b
---c
```

I want the result to be the following:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

How do I implement this? Please help.

Comment: check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WEVE/94/)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to declare the data within the template?

Comment: check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WEVE/95/). Refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [zipped](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext-method-zip) array as the data source

```
var t = new Ext.XTemplate(tpl);
panel.update(t.apply({ titleArr: Ext.zip(data.rowTitleArr, data.colTitleArr) }));
```

Little warning: [Ext.zip](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext-method-zip) is deprecated in ExtJS 4.0.

Maybe you can produce a different `data` like this and iterate through `titleArr`:

```
var data = {
    name: 'xxx',
    titleArr: [
        { row: '1', col: 'a' },
        { row: '2', col: 'b' },
        { row: '3', col: 'c' }
    ]
};
```